# In Haskell, what does it mean if a binding "shadows an existing binding"?

Tags: haskell, compiler-warnings, ghc

I'm getting a warning from GHC when I compile:

> Warning: This binding for 'pats' shadows an existing binding in the definition of 'match_ignore_ancs'

Here's the function:

```
match_ignore_ancs (TextPat _ c) (Text t) = c t
match_ignore_ancs (TextPat _ _) (Element _ _ _) = False
match_ignore_ancs (ElemPat _ _ _) (Text t) = False
match_ignore_ancs (ElemPat _ c pats) (Element t avs xs) =
   c t avs && match_pats pats xs
```

Any idea what this means and how I can fix it?

Cheers.

Comment: What would happen if you rename both `pats` in `match_ignore_ancs` to something else, e. g. `pats1` ?

Comment: An obvious next question is: "How does one find out where that existing binding comes from?". That is, in the current module, or which imported module?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

It means that you have a symbol `pats` defined somewhere else in your program or imported from some library module, and it's visible in the same scope as `match_ignore_ancs`, so when you name a parameter `pats`, it hides (i.e. "shadows") that existing symbol.

Just rename the `pats` parameter to something that doesn't have a collision.