# In ghci, how to remove an existing binding?

Tags: haskell, ghci

I am getting a "binding shadows the existing binding" error similar to the one from [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2902716/in-haskell-what-does-it-mean-if-a-binding-shadows-an-existing-binding) question.

```
Prelude Api.Facility Control.Monad.IO.Class> let t = getBadgesNot 1 (Nothing) (Just 1)

<interactive>:55:5: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for ‘t’ shadows the existing binding
      defined at <interactive>:39:5
```

I defined the existing binding earlier in the session, and am now trying to redefine it. **Is there a way to remove the existing binding so that I can redefine `t`?**

I notice that in other circumstances ghci does not error when redefining an existing binding. For example

```
Prelude> let t = 1
Prelude> let t = 2
Prelude> let t = "there"
```

**Why does ghci error when redefining an existing binding in some cases and not in others?**

Comment: try `Prelude> :unset -Wname-shadowing`. and it says "warning" there, not "error".

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> Is there a way to remove the existing binding so that I can redefine `t`?

No, you cannot remove the existing binding. However, you can redefine `t` at any time, no problem.

> Why does ghci error when redefining an existing binding in some cases and not in others?

Because you ran ghci with different warning/error settings; e.g. by passing `-Wname-shadowing` on the command line (perhaps because you ran ghci through cabal or stack, and the associated project specifies this option in its .cabal file). N.B. `-Wname-shadowing` should not prevent you from redefining `t` unless combined with `-Werror` to turn the mere warning into a full-blown error.

The behavior also appears to differ depending on whether you use `let` or not; this is probably a bug:

```
% ghci -Wname-shadowing -Werror
> let t=3
> let t=4
<interactive>:3:5: warning: [-Wname-shadowing]
    This binding for ‘t’ shadows the existing binding
      defined at <interactive>:1:5

<no location info>: error: 
Failing due to -Werror.
> t
3
> t=4
> t
4
```

Comment: `let` is optional in ghci now?