# How to change a variable's value in GHCI debugger?

Tags: haskell, ghci

Is it possible to change a variable's value in GHCI debugger?
If yes, please show me how?

Comment: No, one of the important design principles of Haskell is that *all* variables are immutable.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [In ghci, how to remove an existing binding?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44894152/in-ghci-how-to-remove-an-existing-binding)

Answer (score 0):

If you have a variable first defined as:

```
x = 7 :: Integer
```

Then if you want to redefine `x`, then all you need to do is:

```
x = "Hello!"
```

Note that this will not affect functions whose body contains `x`, for example:

```
> x = 7 : Integer
> f = (+ x)
> f 10
17
> x = "Hello!"
> f 10
17
```

You will have to redefine any function whose body contains `x` in order for the change to take affect.